# Get matrix row indices for non zero sumrows and column indices for each of those rows

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix

I have a matrix `a` that looks like this:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    3    0    6
[3,]    0    5    0    0    0
[4,]    6    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

I have this code which is intended to do operations if the matrix entry is not zero.

```
for(i in 1:5){
    for(j in 1:5){
        if(sum(a[i,]) == 0 && i <= 5) {
            i+1
        } else {
            if(a[i,j] == 0 && j <= 5){
                j+1
            } else {
            justi = i+i
            bothij = i+j
            print(justi)
            print(bothij)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the operations will only apply for the following entries:

```
[1] "2,3"
[1] "2,5"
[1] "3,2"
[1] "4,1"
```

The result of the above code is:

```
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 4
[1] 7
[1] 6
[1] 5
[1] 8
[1] 5
```

How can I have just `i+i` performed once for each `i`?

Comment: Why don't you use the transpose function for this then? `t()`

Comment: what are the lines `i+1` and `j+1` supposed to be doing?

Comment: `i+1` is skipping the rows that are zero and `j+1` is skipping the column that is zero

Comment: `i+1` and `j+1` do nothing here.  For one thing there is no assignment.  For another, if you change the index of a for loop in R it does not affect the next iteration.  See `?"for"`

Comment: Can you explain in words what you want to do?  You can do a single operation on every nonzero entry by referencing `a[a!=0]` but it looks like you want to be adding indices instead of values or something.  I could probably come up with a single line that does what you are doing but if this is not what you are really doing, that would be a waste.  BTW, in your for loop, use `next` or `break` to go to the next iteration or exit the inner loop, respectively.

Comment: Agree that we need clarity on what is being attempted. Using failing code to present a problem description is a recipe for further failure, or confusion at best. I'm wondering if the answer is to look at the `next` command but that's sheer speculation.

Comment: @farnsy Sorry if I didn't explain myself ok. English is not my mother language. Yes, I want to do the operations with the indices, not the matrix entries themselves. Those entries are just to know if an operation should be done (if the entry is non-zero). What I want to achieve is to have `i+i` performed once for each `i` (ie for each row where the total sum is not zero), in the example above, for rows 2,3 and 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved what I wanted to do:

```
for(i in 1:5){
    if(sum(a[i,]) != 0) {
        justi= i+i 
        print(justi)
        for(j in 1:5){
            if(a[i,j] != 0){
                bothij = i+j
                print(bothij)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That way I get:

```
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 7
[1] 6
[1] 5
[1] 8
[1] 5
```

i.e. `i+i` once for each row.

If someone has a faster answer, I am opened to suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Have you try this?

`a_vector <- a[a > 0]`

then with the `a_vector` do some `stuff` for each `index`